Jaxb timestamp xmlAdapter not working while unmarshalling
I'm trying to unmarshall the given XML to the java object, everything except from the timestamp is populating. I wrote a custom xmlAdapter to parse the timestamp, but while debugging, it never stops there, neither it populates the field.
Example XML:
`"<RootElement>" +
    "<Id>4</Id>" +
    "<Number>628</Number>" +
    "<rId>110080110</rId>" +
    "<OrderNmbr>1234</OrderNmbr>" +
    "<Responses>" +
    "   <Response>" +
    "       <Date>2016-10-21T12:56:19.549+05:30</Date>" +
    "       <Premium>1232131</Premium>" +
            "<Income>1231232</Income>" +
            "<E1>251345</E1>" +
            "<E2>7645233</E2>" +
            "<Tags>" +
            "   <Tag>" +
            "       <timeStamp xsi:type=\"java:java.lang.String\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">1970-01-10 02:07:36.453</timeStamp>" +
            "       <Cd>3425235</Cd>" +
            "       <Cd1>1</Cd1>" +
            "       <ValText>1</ValText>" +
            "       <TokenId>1234</TokenId>" +
            "   </Tag>" +
            "   <Tag>" +
            "       <timeStamp xsi:type=\"java:java.lang.String\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">1970-01-10 02:07:36.453</timeStamp>" +
            "       <Cd>3425236</Cd>" +
            "       <Cd1>2</Cd1>" +
            "       <ValText>2</ValText>" +
            "       <TokenId>1235</TokenId>" +
            "   </Tag>" +
            "</Tags>" +
        "</Response>" +
    "</Responses>" +
"</RootElement>";
`
//classes in my project.

`@XmlRootElement(name = "RootElement")
public class ExampleClass {

@XmlElement(name = "Id")
protected String pId;
@XmlElement(name = "Number")
protected Integer cNumber;
protected Integer rId;
protected String orderNmbr;
@XmlElementWrapper(name = "responses")
@XmlElement(name = "Response")
protected List<Response> responses;
// Getters and setters
        
public class Response {

protected Date date;                    
protected BigDecimal premium;       
protected BigDecimal income;            
protected BigDecimal e1;                    
protected BigDecimal e2;                    
protected List<Tag> tags;
// Getters and setters
    
        
public class Tag {

@XmlElement(name = "timeStamp", namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", type =  String.class)
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CustomTimeStampAdapter.class)
protected Timestamp timeStamp;
protected Integer cd;
protected Integer cd1;
protected String valText;
protected String tokenId;
// Getters and setters
`

//here is my custom adapter.
`public class CustomTimeStampAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Timestamp> {


/**
 * Convert a value type to a bound type.
 *
 * @param timeStamp The value to be converted. Can be null.
 * @throws Exception if there's an error during the conversion. The caller is responsible for
 *                   reporting the error to the user through {@link ValidationEventHandler}.
 */
@Override
public Timestamp unmarshal(String timeStamp) throws Exception {
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(timeStamp)) {
        return null;
    }
    return Timestamp.valueOf(timeStamp.trim());
}

/**
 * Convert a bound type to a value type.
 *
 * @param timeStamp The value to be convereted. Can be null.
 * @throws Exception if there's an error during the conversion. The caller is responsible for
 *                   reporting the error to the user through {@link ValidationEventHandler}.
 */
@Override
public String marshal(Timestamp timeStamp) throws Exception {
    return timeStamp.toString();
}
}`

//bean for jaxb
`@Bean(name = "jaxb2Marshaller")
public Jaxb2Marshaller getJaxb2Marshaller() {
    Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    jaxb2Marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(
            //all the classes the context needs to know about
       ExampleClass.class, Response.class, Tag.class);

    return jaxb2Marshaller;
}`

All the elements are populating except for "timeStamp". What am I missing? Please Help!
Update: -
While testing, I tried removing the "xsi:type="java:java.lang.String" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" from the timestamp node, and the debugger stops at CustomTimeStampAdapter, and I'm able to convert the timestamp string to TimeStamp. So I'm missing something with the namespace. Will continue digging.

The terribly flawed Date and Timestamp classes were years ago supplanted by the modern java.time classes defined in JSR 310, built into Java 8+.

@BasilBourque- I know, but I cannot change what the client is sending in and wants us to save it. So this is the requirement. why the downvote.

Not my downvote. But I could imagine a downvote for not bothering to contrive a simplified [MCVE].

it's just a naming mistake, you annotated bean property as "timestamp"
@XmlElement(name = "timeStamp", namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", type =  String.class)
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CustomTimeStampAdapter.class)
protected Timestamp timeStamp;

whereas in XML relevant tag is named "Id"
"   <Tag>" +
            "       <Id xsi:type=\"java:java.lang.String\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">1970-01-10 02:07:36.453</Id>" +
            "       <Cd>3425235</Cd>" +
            "       <Cd1>1</Cd1>" +
            "       <ValText>1</ValText>" +
            "       <TokenId>1234</TokenId>" +
            "   </Tag>"

Just change name value in @XmlElement annotation to "Id".

thanks for taking the time out to respond to my question,
that was a typo while writing this question on Stack overflow, Corrected the question.
